# How to get an attribute in HTML/XML?

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

Here is a piece of html to be parsed:

```
<td style="text-align:center; color:black; background:#ff6666; border:2px solid #8811ff;"   title="Alkali metals; Primordial; Solid">
37  
<br />  
<a title="Rubidium" href="/wiki/Rubidium">Rb</a>  
</td>`
```

I can get the values with `xmlValue`.
What I get is:

```
text   br    a   
"19"   ""  "K"
```

But I want to get the value of attribute, in `td`, the attribute of `title`, value is *"Alkali metals; Primordial; Solid"* in `a` , the attribute of `title`, value is *"Rubidium"*.

How can I get it?

Comment: BTW: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393780/scraping-a-wiki-page-for-the-periodic-table-and-all-the-links) SO question does help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `xmlAttrs` or `xmlGetAttr` (see `?xmlAttrs` for details).

```
html <- '<td style="text-align:center; color:black; background:#ff6666; border:2px solid #8811ff;" title="Alkali metals; Primordial; Solid">37<br /><a title="Rubidium" href="/wiki/Rubidium">Rb</a></td>'
td <- xmlRoot(xmlParse(html))
xmlAttrs(td)["title"]
# "Alkali metals; Primordial; Solid"
xmlAttrs(xmlChildren(td)$a)["title"]
# "Rubidium

# or
xmlGetAttr(td, "title")
# "Alkali metals; Primordial; Solid"
```