# Scraping related pages in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from several sister URLs for analysis. A previous thread [Scraping a web page, links on a page, and forming a table with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385801/scraping-a-web-page-links-on-a-page-and-forming-a-table-with-r) was helpful in getting me on the right path with the following script:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(XML)
library(RCurl) 

#=======2013========================================================================
url2013 = 'http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2013/en/index.html'
doc <- htmlParse(url2013)
dummy2013 <- data.frame(
  dates = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a', xmlValue),
  hrefs = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a', xmlGetAttr,'href'),
  title = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="link_info"]/text()',  xmlValue)
)

dummy2013$text = unlist(lapply(dummy2013$hrefs,function(x)
{
  url.story <- gsub('/entity','http://www.who.int',x)
  texts <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(url.story), 
                       '//*[@id="primary"]',xmlValue)
}))

dummy2013$link <- gsub('/entity','http://www.who.int',dummy2013$hrefs)

write.csv(dummy2013, "whoDON2013.csv")
```

However, applied to sister URLs, things break. Trying

```
#=======2011========================================================================
url2011 = 'http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2011/en/index.html'
doc <- htmlParse(url2011)
dummy2011 <- data.frame(
  dates = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a', xmlValue),
  hrefs = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a', xmlGetAttr,'href'),
  title = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="link_info"]/text()',  xmlValue)
)
```

for example, produces

```
## Error in data.frame(dates = xpathSApply(doc, "//*[@class=\"auto_archive\"]/li/a",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 59, 60
```

Similar errors occur for http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2008/en/index.html and http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2006/en/index.html. I'm not handy with HTML or XML; any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I guess The error occurs because for a date you have more than one story. The script assume that you have one to one relation story->date.

Comment: You could probably leverage that stories are all grouped under `<li></li>` to catch these kind of duplicate `"link_info"`'s.

Comment: Thanks, though it's not clear to me that the duplicate dates are the issue -- the same script works for 2012 (http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2011/en/index.html), for example, and successfully scrapes three stories that occurred on 23 November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the titles first then find the href associated with them

```
require(XML)
url2011 = 'http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2011/en/index.html'
doc <- htmlParse(url2011)
titleNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, '//*[@class="link_info"]')
hrefNodes <- sapply(titleNodes, getNodeSet, path = './preceding-sibling::a')

dummy2011 <- data.frame(
    dates = sapply(hrefNodes, xmlValue),
    hrefs = sapply(hrefNodes, xmlAttrs),
    title = sapply(titleNodes, xmlValue),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

UPDATE:

to remove duplicate values you can use

```
dummy2011 <- dummy2011[!duplicated(dummy2011$hrefs),]
```

Comment: @user2535366 +1! good idea to use the preceeding value, maybe you can add th length of the result...

Answer (score 0):

After looking more carefully at the HTML code in question I discovered some inconsistencies that tripped up the scripts I was applying. For the record, the following works (admittedly ugly and ad hoc-ish -- but it gets the job done):

```
#=======2011========================================================================
url2011 = 'http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/year/2011/en/index.html'
doc <- htmlParse(url2011)

dates = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a',xmlValue)
hrefs = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="auto_archive"]/li/a',xmlGetAttr,'href')
title = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@class="link_info"]/text()' ,xmlValue)
title[5] <- "Influenza like illness in the United States of America Revised 7 December 2011"
title = title[-6]

dummy2011 <- data.frame(
  dates,
  hrefs,
  title
)
```

Thank you to those who jumped in to help me see my way through this, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I have added an update to my solution which addresses your needs.

Comment: @user2535366 I think it is better and safer to use/try user1609452 solution (his last edit) and maybe you can accept his solution..